# iOS iPhone Getting 1 to Many Entity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, entities

Basically I have an entity that contains food dishes and another that contains wine. Each dish has wine recommendations. I need to be able to select a dish and see the wine recommendations that come with that dish. Different dishes can have the same wine recommended for it.

Normally in SQL I would create a link table to achieve this but I am a bit stumped here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data handles the details of "to-many" relationships under the hood for you, you don't need to make intermediary tables.

Open your Core Data .xcdatamodel file, select the `Food` Entity, and click `Add Relationship`.  Name the relationship `wines`.  Make its destination entity the `Wine` entity.  Open the `Data Model Inspector` (option-cmd-3) and select `To-Many Relationship`.

Now select the `Wine` entity.  Create a relationship called `foods`.  In the `Data Model Inspector` make the relationship's `Desination` the `Food` entity, it's inverse relationship is `wines` and set it to be a `To-Many Relationship` as well.

Now each instance of `Food` can have many `Wine`s and each instance of `Wine` can have many `Food`s.

Comment: Thanks will check this out tomorrow.

Comment: Now I have this set up how would I query the wines entity to return the food that goes with them and visa versa?

Comment: `NSSet *aSetOfFoodInstances = myWine.foods;`

Comment: Where do I put this in my fetch request?

Comment: ALso it must have created a relationship table, how does that get populated with the relevant wine to food links?

Comment: iamsmug - please post general questions about Core Data separately, in the meantime, if you've found any of these answers helpful in resolving your original question, please consider accepting

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Core Data, then you can simply create a Wine table in the database and use it's primary key as the foreign-key in the food-dishes table. What is not working in this design?

Comment: A dish has  more than one wine recommendation, I am using Core Data, I have a food table and a wine table. There has to be another table in my mid to link the 2.